# Flutter to apply styling to the child widget Is it necessary to wrap it inside a Container Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it necessary to use wrap another widget (ie Text, image etc) inside the Container widget as a child, if we want to apply styling to the child widget? In other words, can I apply styling to my Text or Image widgets without wrapping them inside Container widgets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its is necessary to wrap your widget using a `Container` or `DecoratedBox`.

The reason is that in flutter decorations are applied using the `BoxDecoration` class. If you want use styles like Borders, Background Colors Shadows etc you would need to use a Widget that uses a `BoxDecoration`.

If you don't want to use a `Container` you can use the `DecoratedBox` widget provided by flutter amongst others.

If you want to apply styles only to your text data, then you don't need to use `Container` or `DecoratedBox`, as pure text styles can be provided to the `Text` Widget, by providing the style property with the a `TextStyle` Class.

[DecoratedBox Widget Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html)

[BoxDecoration Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)

[TextStyle Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextStyle-class.html)